# How to determine if an Ethereum transaction is an ether transfer?

Tags: ethereum

When I have an Ethereum transaction such as the following

```
{
    "blockHash": "0x9270446bdb76c439792e0711e35e82e39c87174ab3f42734103f93d9b32f3008",
    "blockNumber": "0x1164689",
    "from": "0xcca00a5967b49fdc58238dbc46b0ca8af6b3060a",
    "gas": "0xcb0d",
    "gasPrice": "0x21fcda5db",
    "maxPriorityFeePerGas": "0x5f5e100",
    "maxFeePerGas": "0x3133e7620",
    "hash": "0x4c3336dfe75d04448a63a365930f105830bd48c1ee0108cda2a4081920e67355",
    "input": "0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000050327c6c5a14dcade707abad2e27eb517df87ab500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000047e8320",
    "nonce": "0xb",
    "to": "0x50327c6c5a14dcade707abad2e27eb517df87ab5",
    "transactionIndex": "0x80",
    "value": "0x0",
    "type": "0x2",
    "accessList": [],
    "chainId": "0x1",
    "v": "0x0",
    "r": "0x6622b640499fad5bccd6a33461b371696f524b2ce32f6b7c04eb76914d694829",
    "s": "0x4637ba95c9cfdd3d971d8637bd4bab8a8a6d3e821f7638517f13cad05c6842d"
}
```

How do I determine if this is a contract call or an Ether transfer with a note in its input without making external calls?

I know the example transaction is a contract call. I am asking in general.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I determine if this is a contract call or an Ether transfer with a note in its input without making external calls?

You can validate if the `to` address holds a contract bytecode.

Example with the [ethers](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/) JS library:

```
if (await provider.getCode("0x50327c6c5a14dcade707abad2e27eb517df87ab5") == "0x") {
    console.log("not contract");
} else {
    console.log("is contract");
}
```

Docs: https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/providers/#Provider-getCode

Or a raw RPC call to the node:

```
curl --location 'YOUR_RPC_PROVIDER' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data '{"method":"eth_getCode","params":["0x50327c6c5a14dcade707abad2e27eb517df87ab5", "latest"], "id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0"}'
```

Docs: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_getcode

---

The examples above only check if the address is a contract at the current block.

It's also possible that the address wasn't a contract yet at the time of the transaction - but now is. Or the other way around - was a contract, and now is destructed.

If you want this level of precision, both methods (the `ethers` library, which is a wrapper to RPC, as well as the actual raw RPC call) enable you to specify the block number at which you want to query the state. However your node provider needs to support this archival data retrieval, and currently most node providers only support it in their paid plans (or you can always run your own archival node that's not limited).

Comment: Thank you for the solution but I specifically asked if this is possible without making external calls.

Comment: @M.Azyoksul I originally understood your "external calls" as "invoking `eth_call` to the address"... Unforunately, the transaction (nor transaction receipt) object does not hold any information whether the `to` address is a contract or not. So it's not possible to find out if the address is a contract without an additional call... Note: The `gas` for non-contract interaction is by default 21000, but it can also be higher if the sender sets a higher value. So that's also not a 100% precise solution.